# Ext.net textfield and lable are hidden in compatability mode in IE

Tags: asp.net, extjs, extjs4, ext.net

I am using Ext.Net 2.
But in Ext.Window my textfiels and lable control get disable in comparability mode in IE.
in Normal mode it looks fine.

when I set the Hidden=true this problem arise.

and when I add HideMode="Display" all control load but panel title get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made change in  to  for window and use Hidden="true" HideMode="display".
Now I can able to find perfect UI even in compatibility Mode of IE

```
    <ext:Window ID="Window" runat="server" Title="Title of Form" Icon="Email"
      Hidden="true" HideMode="display">
      **<Items>**
        <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
          <Content>
             ........................
             ......................
          </Content>
        </ext:Panel>
        <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
          <Content>
             ........................
             ......................
          </Content>
        </ext:Panel>
      **</Items>**
     </ext:Window>
```